# I need to transform an SQL arguments into Sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to transform an SQL arguments into Sequelize

```sql
SELECT `WeekHours`.`id_weekhours` AS `idWeekhours`, `WeekHours`.`hour`, `WeekHours`.`week_day` AS `weekDay` 
FROM `week_hours` AS `WeekHours` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_schedule` AS `UserSchedule` 
ON `WeekHours`.`id_weekhours` = `UserSchedule`.`id_weekhours` AND `UserSchedule`.`date` = '2021-05-03' 
WHERE `UserSchedule`.`id_weekhours` IS NULL AND `WeekHours`.`week_day` = 'Monday';
```

I created this in sequelize:

```js
await WeekHours.findAll({
  attributes: ['hour', 'weekDay'],
  where: {
    idWeekhours: {
      [Op.eq]: null
    },
    weekDay,
  },
  include: [{
    attributes: [],
    model: UserSchedule,
    where: {
      date,
    },
    required: false,
  }],
})
```

but i get that:

```sql
SELECT `WeekHours`.`id_weekhours` AS `idWeekhours`, `WeekHours`.`hour`, `WeekHours`.`week_day` AS `weekDay` 
FROM `week_hours` AS `WeekHours` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_schedule` AS `UserSchedule` ON `WeekHours`.`id_weekhours` = `UserSchedule`.`id_schedule` AND `UserSchedule`.`date` = '2021-05-03' 
WHERE `WeekHours`.`id_weekhours` IS NULL AND `WeekHours`.`week_day` = 'Monday';
```

the issues that i have is:

wrong:

```
`WHERE `WeekHours`.`id_weekhours
```

correct:

```
`WHERE `UserSchedule`.`id_weekhours
```

---

wrong:

```
`ON `WeekHours`.`id_weekhours` = `UserSchedule`.`id_schedule
```

correct:

```
`ON `WeekHours`.`id_weekhours` = `UserSchedule`.`id_weekhours
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const usedHours = await WeekHours.findAll({
      attributes: ['hora'],
      where: {
        '$UserSchedule.id_weekhours$': {
          [Op.eq]: null
        },
        diaSemana,
      },
      include: [{
        attributes: [],
        model: UserSchedule,
        on: {
          id: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col("WeekHours.id_weekhours"), "=",Sequelize.col("UserSchedule.id_weekhours"))
        },
        where: {
          data,
        },
        required: false,
      }],
    })
```